# sails waterline autoincrement

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Curious why this behavior is happening...

When I lift sails for testing, I set up a testdb on disk.  Everything is dropped to start the tests with a clean slate.

```
Sails.lift({
  connections: {
    testdb: {
      adapter: 'sails-disk'
    },
  },
  models: {
    connection: 'testdb',
    migrate: 'drop'
 }
}, function(err, server) ...
```

When I do Model.find() before a test, everything is predictably empty.  But when I do Model.create(), it returns the "id" fields incremented in sequence from all the old models.

Switching to the 'sails-memory' adapter starts fresh each time, which makes sense because it is physically unable to persist anything.

So, just as a point of learning, what's going on here and why?

Comment: looks like you found a bug in sails-disk, the drop function clears the data and the schema but doesn't clear the counters. you can open it as an issue in the sails-disk github repo.

Comment: fun!  https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk/issues/41

Answer (score -1):

You have your model migrate set to `drop`. According to [sails migrate doc](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings), you will need to set it to `save` or `alter`.